# How to click the button in the cell of webtable

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

Suppose webtable contains 5 rows and 5 columns and my is requirement is I want to click button inside cell no 3rd row and 4th column. How can I get that can I get the code.

Comment: it is static webtable and suppose if it is a dynamic webtable then?

Answer (score 1):

QTP/UFT provides the `.ChildItem` method for this.

```
Browser("B").Page("P").WebTable("WT").ChildItem(3, 4, "Link", 1).Click
```

The syntax being `ChildItem(row, col, micClass, ItemIndex)`

If it is a dynamic table, then get the number of rows using `.RowCount` and columns using `.ColumnCount` method at run time.

A variation of your question is [discussed in detail here](https://www.learnqtp.com/forums/Thread-Webtable-contains-cell-contains-two-links-how-to-click-on-link).